# Customised X-axis ticks in Scatter Plot using Openpyxl python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to add customized x-axis ticks from particular column values,
similar to `set_categories` of a pie-chart. I have gone through the documentation and failed to find any solution.
Below is my code:

```
from openpyxl.chart import ScatterChart, Reference, Series 
wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 
sheet = wb.active 
rows = [ 
    ("Number", "Sales", "Market")   , 
    ("Number of Products", "Sales in USD", "Market share"), 
    ('0x1', 12200, 15), 
    ('0x2', 60000, 33), 
    ('0x3', 24400, 10), 
    ('0x4', 32000, 42), 
] 
for row in rows: 
    sheet.append(row) 
  
chart = ScatterChart() 
  
xvalues = Reference(sheet, min_col = 1, min_row = 3, max_row = 6) 
yvalues = Reference(sheet, min_col = 2,   min_row = 3, max_row = 6) 
size = Reference(sheet, min_col = 3,  min_row = 3, max_row = 6) 
series = Series(values = yvalues, xvalues =xvalues , zvalues =size , title ="2013") 
chart.series.append(series) 
  
chart.title = " SCATTER-CHART "
chart.x_axis.title = " X_AXIS "
chart.y_axis.title = " Y_AXIS "
sheet.add_chart(chart, "E2") 
wb.save(" ScatterChart.xlsx")
```

Can any one tell me how to add `xvalues` to x-axis ticks.
This is the expected graph I am looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows:

- You want to add `xvalues` to x-axis ticks
- You want to do this by creating a simple line chart?

**Observations:**

- You are creating a `ScatterChart` and trying to set x-axis ticks using string labels, which is not supported by this chart type, only numeric values are supported.

**Solution**

1. Change chart type from `ScatterChart` to `LineChart` (or `BarChart` if still serves the same objective).
2. Modify the chart build parameters

**Modified Solution Code:**

- **LINE CHART**

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart

wb = Workbook() 
sheet = wb.active 

rows = [ 
    ("Number", "Sales", "Market")   , 
    ("Number of Products", "Sales in USD", "Market share"), 
    ('0x1', 12200, 15), 
    ('0x2', 60000, 33), 
    ('0x3', 24400, 10), 
    ('0x4', 32000, 42), 
] 
for row in rows: 
    sheet.append(row) 

# build chart
chart = LineChart() 
# label chart
chart.title = " SCATTER-CHART "
chart.x_axis.title = " X_AXIS "
chart.y_axis.title = " Y_AXIS "

# define data series and domain range
xvalues = Reference(sheet, min_col = 1, min_row = 3, max_row = 6) 
yvalues = Reference(sheet, min_col = 2, min_row = 3, max_row = 6) 
# add data to chart
chart.add_data(yvalues)
chart.set_categories(xvalues)
sheet.add_chart(chart, 'E2')
# save file
wb.save('LineChart.xlsx')
```

[Output chart image](https://ibb.co/HXsVf6c)